# How to log data in console/webjob output and on azure apps service with application insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-webjobs

I am using webjobs **v3** with HostBuilder.

How do I have to configure the logger that I can use a telemetryClient to tracktrace data which is visible in the console output AND visible in the azure app service
this webjob is running on?

I would like to get a ILogger instance which logs to console AND azure.

this line of code:

```
 var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogInformation("I log only in the console but not azure.");
```

DOES not send its data to azure application insights charts...

I do NOT want to use the ILogger AND the telemetryclient to log stuff that would be stupid.

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .UseEnvironment("Development")
                .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
                {
                    // Add extensions and other WebJobs services
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(b =>
                {

                    // Add configuration sources          
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
                {
                    // Add Logging Providers
                    b.AddConsole(); 


                    // If this key exists in any config, use it to enable App Insights
                    string appInsightsKey = context.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"]; // taken from the appservice environmentvariable

                    appInsightsKey = "xxxxxxxx";

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appInsightsKey))
                    {
                        // This uses the options callback to explicitly set the instrumentation key.
                        b.AddApplicationInsights(o => o.InstrumentationKey = appInsightsKey);
                    }
                })
                .UseConsoleLifetime();

            var host = builder.Build();

            // my code like telemetryClient.TrackTrace("show this text in console output AND azure app service where this webjob belongs to")

            using (host)
            {
                host.Run();
            }
```

Comment: what do you mean "I do NOT want to use the ILogger AND the telemetryclient to log stuff"?

Comment: I do not want to use TWO api`s to log parallel in 2 places when running my code locally for DEV environment.

Comment: ok, you want to use ILogger to log the message to console and application insights in azure portal, right？

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I misunderstand you.

For "I would like to get a ILogger instance which logs to console AND azure", I'm using the code below:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
                {
                    b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                    b.AddAzureStorage();
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(b =>
                {

                }
                )
                .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
                {

                    b.AddConsole();
                    string instrumentationKey = context.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentationKey))
                    {
                        b.AddApplicationInsights(o => o.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey);
                    }
                })                
                .UseConsoleLifetime();

            var host = builder.Build();

            var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogInformation("hello 111111111111111");

            using (host)
            {
                host.Run();
            }
        }
```

After running the code, the message is logged in console and app insights in azure portal:

[image]

Comment: It just did not sent it to azure for me.

Comment: @HelloWorld, can you please make sure your application insights instrumentation key is correct? then just for testing purpose, can you please just hardcode the instrumentation key in your code to see if it can be logged in azure? And also please let me know you run it from local or from azure?

Comment: the telemtry data output does NOT EVEN appear in the output window.

Comment: @HelloWorld, can you please provide more details on this? like which version of nuget package you're using, and the appsettings.json, and are you creating the webjob from template or just a console project? Then I can debug at my side. I think there is a minor error there, since it works at my side.